# Error in SQL Developer

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got connected to database from sql developer. after that I couldn't able to run any query. it is not showing any database objects under the connection string. 
I have seen the following error. 
can anybody help me to resolve the issue?

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '0'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2503)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2485)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2367)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2769)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.internal.SimpleRaptorTaskUI.getFormattedTime(SimpleRaptorTaskUI.java:219)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.internal.RaptorTaskUI.setState(RaptorTaskUI.java:43)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.internal.SimpleRaptorTaskUI.<init>(SimpleRaptorTaskUI.java:59)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.internal.RaptorTaskUI.<init>(RaptorTaskUI.java:36)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.ui.TaskProgressViewer$4.<init>(TaskProgressViewer.java:297)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.ui.TaskProgressViewer.createTaskUI(TaskProgressViewer.java:297)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager.initViewers(RaptorTaskManager.java:338)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager.addTask(RaptorTaskManager.java:279)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager.addTask(RaptorTaskManager.java:184)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager.addTask(RaptorTaskManager.java:145)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.OpenWorksheetWizard.invoke(OpenWorksheetWizard.java:351)
    at oracle.ide.wizard.WizardManager.invokeWizard(WizardManager.java:372)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.WorksheetOpenController$1.run(WorksheetOpenController.java:67)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.WorksheetOpenController.openWorksheetWizard(WorksheetOpenController.java:73)
    at oracle.dbtools.worksheet.editor.WorksheetOpenController.handleEvent(WorksheetOpenController.java:34)
    at oracle.ideimpl.controller.IdeActionHook$MetaClassController.handleEvent(IdeActionHook.java:414)
    at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.performAction(IdeAction.java:529)
    at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformedImpl(IdeAction.java:884)
    at oracle.ide.controller.IdeAction.actionPerformed(IdeAction.java:501)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at oracle.ide.controls.ActionMenuToolButton.access$400(ActionMenuToolButton.java:82)
    at oracle.ide.controls.ActionMenuToolButton$FilterActionEvents.actionPerformed(ActionMenuToolButton.java:394)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:291)
    at oracle.ide.controls.ActionMenuToolButton$2.setPressed(ActionMenuToolButton.java:223)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:273)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:668)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:639)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: A Java stack trace that's 50 calls deep and not one mention of `Factory`? [Mind = Blown](http://www.bradbranson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/his_mind-blown.gif).

Comment: Are you using the version of Java required by the version of SQL Developer you have?

Answer (score 0):

In my case language for windows was not "English(United States)".

So after changing the language preference and restarting the SQL developer resolved the issue.